# Need help with Modal: move mouse - increase step value

Tags: python, operator

Simple operator with select more/less.
I need to increase/decrease step value by moving mouse.

```
import bpy

class ModalSelection(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "modal.selection"
    bl_label = "Modal Selection"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    value_count : bpy.props.IntProperty(
        name="Step number",
        description="Select more/less modal",
        default=1, 
        min=0, 
        step=1
    )
    
    def more_less(self, context):
        for i in range(0, self.value_count):
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()
        
    def modal(self, context, event):        
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC', 'LEFTMOUSE'}:
            return {'FINISHED'}

        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            self.value_count = round(abs(event.mouse_x * 0.005))
            #self.value_count = round(event.mouse_x * 0.005)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):        
        if context.edit_object:
            
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
    def execute(self, context):        
        self.more_less(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalSelection)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalSelection)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that because once this is run `for i in range(0,self.value_count):            bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()` the selection state is messed up. You would have to save the selection state at the start of the operator in `invoke` (storing all the selected vertices indices somewhere) then reselect them every time you run the modal. Otherwise you'll end up only increasing the number of selected stuff

Comment: Also even if that worked, you need to store somewhere the position of the mouse when you first run the operator. eg `self.value_count = round((event.mouse_x - self.mouse_start)*0.05)`

Comment: Understood. Thank you!